# How to fix cut of UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a UILabel inside a UIStackView in a xib file. the label is cut off. What I am trying to accomplish is have a small UIView circle that will be Green when a user is online and red when they are offline. I embedded the UIView and UILabel in a stack view and set the UIView height and width to be 5. However it is also changing the label, but I want the label to be sized to its text. Any suggestions on how I can fix this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip: it helps to change the names of your elements... Tough to refer to "Stack View" and "View" and "Label" when you have multiple of each.

What you need to do is...

For your Horizontal Stack view that is holding your `5 x 5` sized view, set the **Alignment** to **Center**.

This will allow the stack view to grow tall enough to fit the label, without stretching the height of the `5 x 5` view.